# Exclude empty column from select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a select comand:

```
select 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo = 20190901 then 1 else 0 end) "1" , 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo = 20190902 then 1 else 0 end) "2" , 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo = 20190903 then 1 else 0 end) "3" , 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo = 20190904 then 1 else 0 end) "4" , 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo = 20190905 then 1 else 0 end) "5" , 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo = 20190906 then 1 else 0 end) "6"
from table
```

The result is:

```
 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6
 5 |  0 |  8 |  7 |  0 |  3
```

I like to exclude the columns `2 and 5` because the result is zero, like this:

```
 1 |  3 |  4 |  6
 5 |  8 |  7 |  3
```

Comment: You can't. You better remove it in your app.

Comment: Or unpivot. To get one row per existing co_dim_tempo value.

Comment: @jarlh can you post an example?

Comment: `select co_dim_tempo, count(*) from table where co_dim_tempo  in (20190901, ... 20190906 ) group by co_dim_tempo `

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `COUNT` from the below Query.

The `HAVING` class remove the **0** values from the result.

If we want tot use String functions like **`RIGHT`**, then we have to `CAST` the Datatype of the `co_dim_tempo` to `VARCHAR` FROM `BIGINT`.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(co_dim_tempo AS VARCHAR),1) co_dim_tempo,
    SUM(*) NoOfOccurences
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY RIGHT(CAST(co_dim_tempo AS VARCHAR),1)
HAVING SUM(1) > 0
```

Other than that, the result you are expecting may be possible by `PIVOT` or `Dynamic SQL Query`.

Comment: Do you know that `count(1)` is actually [slower](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/) than `count(*)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I don't know that. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @DineshDB `function RIGHT not exists`

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: @DineshDB PostgreSQL

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, What is the datatype of `co_dim_tempo` column?

Comment: @DineshDB bigint

Comment: this works using `count` but generate only two columns. how to convert the lines to columns?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT RIGHT(CAST(co_dim_tempo AS VARCHAR),1) co_dim_tempo
SUM(*) NOOFOCCURENCES
GROUP BY RIGHT(CAST(co_dim_tempo AS VARCHAR),1)
HAVING SUM(1)>0;